# Prove $\frac{MF}{ID}=\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Circle (O,R) with diameter AB. C On (O), know as $\angle AOC=120^{o}$. Two tangents at point A and C of (O) intersect at M. Draw diameter CD, DM intersect AC at I. Circumsribed circle of triangle MIC intersect CD at F.

Prove $\frac{MF}{ID}=\sqrt{3}$
[image]

I can calculate DC,CM,,DM and tried to use $ID.DM=DF.CF$ and $MF^{2}=MC^{2}+CF^{2}$, so $\frac{MF^2}{ID^2}=\frac{(MC^2+CF^2)DM^2}{DF^2DC^2}=\frac{7(3R^2+CF^2}{4(2R-CF)^2}$ and stuck cause I cant find a way to calculate CF.

Could anyone help me to deal with this problem? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As $\angle MCF = 90^\circ, MF$ must be a diameter of the circumcircle of $\triangle MIC$. So, $IF \perp MD$.

As $\angle AOC = 120^\circ, \triangle ACM$ is equilateral triangle with side length being $R \sqrt3$.

As $\angle ACD = 30^\circ$ and $\triangle CAD$ is right, $AD = CD/2 = R$

Also, $\angle IMF = \angle ICF = 30^\circ$ and as $\triangle MIF$ is right, $IF = MF/2$

Now using $\triangle DIF \sim \triangle DCM$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{IF}{ID} = \frac{CM}{CD} \implies \frac{MF/2}{ID} = \frac{R \sqrt3}{2R}$

$\therefore \dfrac{MF}{ID} = \sqrt3$

Comment: It's really help!! Thank u so much

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You have to show $\triangle ADI\sim \triangle MFC $ and you can write:

$\frac {MF}{DI}=\frac {MC}{AD}=\frac {AC}{AD}$

$\overset{\large\frown}{AD}=60^o$(why?)

$\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{AC}=120^o$

$\Rightarrow \widehat {MAC}=\widehat{MCA}=60^o$

So triangle MAC is equilateral and $MC=AC$

In right angled triangle ADC we have:

$cotan 30^o=\sqrt 3= \frac {AC}{AD}$

Comment: Thank you so much